# Fan for old socket A Athlon cooler

Tags: hardware, hardware-mods, compatibility

I put together a retro gaming setup with a 2000ish spec (can post specs if required) and it's come together pretty nicely except the CPU fan is insanely shrill (it's a Coolermaster something).

If I were to pick up a small cheap silent case fan such as a Gelid Silent, would that have the right kind of screw holes to match what would be typical on an old heatsink?

EDIT: Maybe something like this: https://gelidsolutions.com/thermal-solutions/case-fan-silent-6/

Comment: You should measure the size of the fan, it should be a standard size, e.g. 60, 70 or 80mm, while around 2000 Athlon it probably 60mm. These fans are widely available everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, as 40mm is a very small fan - smaller than the CPU socket.  Usually you would expect to find 60mm or larger fans on a Socket A heatsink.  You should still be able to find complete Socket A compatible heatsinks, if you look in the [right places](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-85x70x50mm-Socket-Heatsink-Connector-Black/dp/B00006B8DB/ref=sr_1_42?keywords=%22socket%2Ba%22&qid=1578650697&s=computers&sr=1-42&th=1).

However, you should also try simply slowing the fan down when the CPU is cool enough to not require its full power.  This is probably the best option if the fan is working correctly, and is just a bit noisy.  There are several ways of doing this; if your m/board doesn't have the feature built in, there are variable resistors to insert in line, or sophisticated fan controller modules which can handle case fans as well as the CPU.

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful. I actually just guessed at the size of the fan (I would of course have measured before buying anything) so you're probably right about 60mm. I will update the question to account for that. The thing with the noise isn't just the volume though but the pitch and nature of the sound. There's a slow (<1Hz) pulsing of volume and something more shrill than just the usual air movement sound (so it's different to a loud overheating laptop for example).

Comment: One other thing I should mention is that the heatsink was a real pain to get off and on and my thermal paste is running low, so while a new heatsink is a possibility, it's not the ideal solution (though I am impressed these are still being made, and cheaply available).